# looping through an array of hashes in a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following code that uses references to hashes:

```
sub readAll {
   my ( $main, $dbh ) = @_;

   my @SessSeq = ();
   my $sql;
   my $rec = 0;
   $sql  = "SELECT * FROM sys_table ";
   my $sth = PrepAndExecuteQuery( $dbh, $sql );
   while ( my $result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ){
      push @SessSeq, $result;
      $rec++;
   }
   $$main{_SessSeq} = \@SessSeq;
}
```

Above code works. i get an array of hashes in the main hash
I'm struggling to retrieve the data due to my lack of knowledge.
this doesnt seem to work:

```
foreach my $ses ( @($$main{_SessSeq}) ){
    print STDERR Dumper $ses;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you might be dereferencing the hash wrong. Try `@{$$main{_SessSeq}}` instead of `@($$main{_SessSeq})`.

Comment: What does *this doesn't seem to work* mean?

Comment: `@{...}` to dereference an array ref, not `@(...)`

Comment: Are you dumping in the sub or outside of it? Keep in mind that you populated the `$main` you created in the sub, but not any similarly named variable outside the sub. If you pass in a reference to an array, the sub will add to the array. If you pass in undef, the sub won't modify anything in the caller.

Comment: The remark of jja helped, i now get the right session. Actually i don't want to dump something of course i want to access the hash in the array of hashes. so: via my $hash = @{$$main{_SessSeq}}[1] ; i can now access the hash. but if i try @{$$main{_SessSeq}}[1]{name} it gives a compile error so this is not recognized. how can i address it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `foreach my $ses` loop is *inside* the `readAll` subroutine, the only thing you are doing wring is to use use parentheses `( ... )` instead of braces `{ ... }`in your dereferencing

`$$main{_SessSeq}` would be very much better written in modern terms as `$main->{_SessSeq}`, but both evaluate to the same thing: a reference to an array of hashes with the data from a database table row in each hash

The correct loop will look like this

```
for my $ses ( @{ $main->{_SessSeq} } ) {
    print STDERR Dumper $ses;
}
```

but there is no real advantage over writing just

```
print STDERR Dumper $main->{_SessSeq}
```

You say nothing about what ***this doesn't seem to work*** might mean, but `print Dumper $ses` will output the contents of a table row each time around the loop

If you need any further help then you must describe the problem properly, showing the output that you're getting and describing carefully what you expect

Comment: Your answer provided me the answer to the problem i had. i now know how to address it